# Facebook Market scraping using class id in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

[Class ID to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v2N5.png)

I wanted to scrape data from facebook market using python and by using this script below however no data is showing when i run the script. Class ID is in the picture above.

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('l9j0dhe7 f9o22wc5 ad2k81qe')                                                        for ele in elements: print(ele.text) print(ele.get_attribute('title'))`

Comment: Please provide if possible - url of website or as minimum content of elements. That would help to get a closer view.

Comment: `url ='https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/109480902404412/search/?category_id=computers&query=imac'
driver.get(url)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there are a few things, you should take a look - `find_element_by_class_name` takes only one class name, you better take use of `find_element_by_css_selector`

**Solution for getting informations based on your information**

Get all results:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('kbiprv82')
```

Loop results and print:

```
for ele in elements: 
    title = ele.find_element_by_css_selector('span.a8c37x1j.ni8dbmo4.stjgntxs.l9j0dhe7').text
    price = ele.find_element_by_css_selector('div.hlyrhctz > span').text
    print(title, price)
```

**Output**

```
IMac 21,5 Ende 2012 380 €
Imac 27 Mitte 2011 (Wie Neu Zustand ) 550 €
iMac 14,2 27" 550 €
```

Hope that helps, let us know.

Comment: Yes that was helpful I alrady have the datafor scraping. I also have other question: I also wanted to scrape the description of the data which will be shown in upon clicking the photo or in the modal... Im stuck on how to point on scraping in the modal for me to extract. Name, Price,Location and Description.

Comment: Concerning your additional question, please ask it as new question. You can refer to this question and take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is the link of my new question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940782/facebook-market-scraping-in-modal-dialog-using-class-id-in-python] or [https://gist.github.com/yeuhanshen/5bec26eaebccd36890e6704e175603a5/revisions]