# Facebook Market scraping in modal dialog using class id in python

Tags: python

I wanted to scrape data in facebook market which is in the dialog box when I click the specific item in the div list the script is running but when I check my csv file nothing is scrape.  I want to scrape all iMac or computers available on that area for market research.

```
str1 ='https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/1496891970531263/search/?category_id=computers&query='
str2 = 'iMac'                            
url = str1 + str2 
driver.get(url) 
time.sleep(3)
                          
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/marketplace.item/')]")

n=10
links = ()

for ii in ids [:n]:
    links+=(ii.get_attribute('href'),)
                          
datalist= []
                          
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    compName = driver.find_element_by_id('marketplace-modal-dialog-title').text
    Loc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sonix8o1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/span[1]').text
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="aov4n071]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/span[2]').text
    desc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="n851cfcs]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[1]').text
                          
    df_text =[compName,Loc,price,desc,link] 
    datalist.append((compName,Loc,price,miles,desc,link))
    ColName=['compName','Loc','price','miles','desc','link']
                          
df = pd.DataFrame(datalist,columns=['compName','Loc','price','desc','link'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Ryzen 5\Desktop\work\Book.csv',index=True,encoding='utf-8') 

from IPython.core.display import display,HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container{width:100% !important;}</style>"))
```

Comment: Facebook is changing its page multiple times a day. Don't expect your scraping approach to work for long.

Comment: yes thats why im also updating the class id every now and then.